# BH multiple correction to different columns in data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with an id field and three different and unrelated p-values. I would like to apply the benjamini-hochberg corection at each column.
I've been working with the `p.adjust` as function `p.adjust(data[,2], "BH")`, but I'm having trouble since I have to sort each column before applying the correction and I lose the id information after that. My data looks like:

```
id  p1  p2  p3
1   ENSG00000179094 1.000000e+00    1.000000e+00    1.000000e+00
2   ENSG00000164306 1.000000e+00    1.000000e+00    1.000000e+00
3   ENSG00000147180 1.000000e+00    8.778847e-02    1.000000e+00
4   ENSG00000172932 4.370119e-01    1.766703e-04    1.000000e+00
5   ENSG00000137252 1.000000e+00    2.562124e-02    1.000000e+00
6   ENSG00000144644 1.654108e-02    1.000000e+00    1.000000e+00
7   ENSG00000197273 3.316301e-01    5.341301e-01    1.000000e+00
8   ENSG00000169221 1.000000e+00    1.000000e+00    1.000000e+00
9   ENSG00000108309 8.689368e-01    2.350522e-03    1.000000e+00
10  ENSG00000172382 1.000000e+00    9.028471e-01    2.697276e-02
11  ENSG00000099937 1.000000e+00    1.000000e+00    9.988716e-01
12  ENSG00000259431 1.000000e+00    1.000000e+00    7.268023e-01
...
```

Is there an easiest way or package to do this without losing the information from the id's?

Comment: It's unclear to me why you think you need to sort the columns. I see nothing in the help page for `p.adjust` that indicates that is needed.

Comment: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/p.adjust.html
In the examples they make a sort

Also the BH methodology involves a ranking as far as I know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **numcolwise** , apply a function to only numeric columns of a data.frame.

```
library(plyr) 
 cbind(dat$id,numcolwise(p.adjust)(dat))
             dat$id       p1          p2        p3
1  ENSG00000179094 1.000000 1.000000000 1.0000000
2  ENSG00000164306 1.000000 1.000000000 1.0000000
3  ENSG00000147180 1.000000 0.790096230 1.0000000
4  ENSG00000172932 1.000000 0.002120044 1.0000000
5  ENSG00000137252 1.000000 0.256212400 1.0000000
6  ENSG00000144644 0.198493 1.000000000 1.0000000
7  ENSG00000197273 1.000000 1.000000000 1.0000000
8  ENSG00000169221 1.000000 1.000000000 1.0000000
9  ENSG00000108309 1.000000 0.025855742 1.0000000
10 ENSG00000172382 1.000000 1.000000000 0.3236731
11 ENSG00000099937 1.000000 1.000000000 1.0000000
12 ENSG00000259431 1.000000 1.000000000 1.0000000
```

To use other arguments:

```
cbind(dat$id,numcolwise(p.adjust)(dat, method = 'bonferroni', n = 20))
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to understand what it does. Apparently numcolwise applies a function to all numerical columns?
Then p.adjust uses BH method by default? And finally how is that we don't need to sort the columns before the p.adjust, is this done automatically?
Thanks

Comment: yes p.adjust use BH metho by default , I update my answer to see how to other parametrs.

Comment: Thanks, it's an amazing one-liner. plyr is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
dat2 <- dat  # only needed if you want to protect original data.
dat2[2:4] <- lapply(dat2[2:4], p.adjust, method="BH")
```

Comment: I find different values using this method and the one detailed by agstudy. Might it be that BH is not the default?

Comment: I double checked and p.adjust DON'T use BH as default method.

Comment: It's not the default .... which was why I specified it as the method. That was what yopu asked for, right?

Comment: You're right. I was just pointing it because **agstudy** said BH was set by default. Since I had different results I had to test which scenario was correct.